# Is there any explaination about [_UIAlertManager hideAlertsForTermination]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I got an error on iPhone5/5s, this is its call stack:

```
20 libsystem_c.dylib 0x381b3850 __cxa_finalize + 159
21 libsystem_c.dylib 0x38173824 exit + 7
22 UIKit 0x2fd6a618 +[_UIAlertManager hideAlertsForTermination]
23 UIKit 0x2fd67b2a -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 2474
24 UIKit 0x2fce9212 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 890
25 UIKit 0x2fce8dd8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 72
26 UIKit 0x2fd4d3e4 __UIApplicationHandleEvent + 616
27 GraphicsServices 0x32356b54 __PurpleEventCallback + 608
28 GraphicsServices 0x3235673e _PurpleEventCallback + 34
29 CoreFoundation 0x2d47d806 ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
30 CoreFoundation 0x2d47d7a2 ___CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 346
31 CoreFoundation 0x2d47bf6e ___CFRunLoopRun + 1406
32 CoreFoundation 0x2d3e6728 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
33 CoreFoundation 0x2d3e650a CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
34 GraphicsServices 0x323556d2 GSEventRunModal + 135
35 UIKit 0x2fd47870 UIApplicationMain + 1135
```

What is the opportunity of this function? Why this function call exit method in depth 22?

Is there any document about this?

Comment: Can you show use some code?

Comment: this is apple internal codes

Comment: ok, i have find the solution.

Comment: @Hikari what was your solution?

Comment: yes @Hikari what was your solution? :)

Comment: hi, facing a similar problem. what's your solution? @Hikari